# Discord.js Ban Command with Command Handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a Discord.js Ban Command with reason and stuff however i overcome an error whenever i try to use it. Here is my code :

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Ban a user from the server by using mentioning them!',
  guildOnly: true,
    aliases: ['ban', 'banbanban'],
    usage: `-ban <USER_MENTION> <OPTIONAL_REASON>`,
    cooldown: 5,
    async execute(message, args, client) {

const daidinevermantion = new MessageEmbed()
        daidinevermantion.setTitle('Incorrect arguments provided!')
        daidinevermantion.setDescription('Please Mention a user to ban ;-;. Make sure it a mention. The bot may not be able to ban users not in the server')
        daidinevermantion.addField('Usage','``;ban <USER_MENTION> <OPTIONAL REASON>``')
        daidinevermantion.addField('Example Usage', ';ban <@760773438775492610> Good Bot')
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the right permissions.')

        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send(daidinevermantion);

        if(!member) return message.channel.send('Can\'t seem to find this user. Sorry \'bout that :/. Make sure you are mentioning the user and the user is in the server!');
        if(!member.bannable) return message.channel.send('This user can\'t be banned. It is either because they are a mod/admin, or their highest role is higher than mine');

        if(member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send('Bruh, you can\'t ban yourself!');

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';

        member.ban({ days: 7, reason: reason }).catch(err => { 
          message.channel.send('Something went wrong')
            console.log(err)
        })

        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Member Banned')
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField('User Banned', member)
        .addField('Banned by', message.author)
        .addField('Reason', reason)
        .setFooter('Banned On:', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(banembed);

    }
}
```

Here whenever i send this command I this message in return "This user can't be banned. It is either because they are a mod/admin, or their highest role is higher than mine" regardless of whatever the case is whether its position is higher or lower. I'm a bit new to Discord.js please help me out thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure your bot have the required permissions to ban a user

Comment: [Member#bannable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=bannable) is based on if the Client itself is able to ban the member, not you. Compare the bot's role to the member you're trying to ban.

Comment: Can you clarify this sentence: "I made a Discord.js Ban Command with reason and stuff however i overcome an error whenever i try to use it."? Should it be "I made a Discord.js Ban Command with a reason and other required parameters. However, I get an error whenever I try to use it."?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that message because `member.bannable` is always false, and the reason for that is your bot doesn't have the required permissions to ban a user. Use this [permission calculator](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html) and reinvite the bot to the server with required permissions i.e "Ban Members" or "Administrator".

Comment: Hey thanks that was quite helpful however after banning I dont recieve a message say this user was banned like i did it in code could you help out a bit!

Comment: Try creating the embed before calling the ban function and then send it like this `member.ban().then(()=>message.channel.send(banembed))`